# Iterating over dynamically enabled/disabled buttons in Prototype

Tags: prototypejs

The following code

```
$$('input[type=button], [enabled=enabled]').each(function(element, index){
    // others tasks here
});
```

allows me to iterate over button elements, those that are not hidden when DOM loads, in Prototype. But the buttons can be enabled/disabled dynamically. That means, I need to add jQuery's .live() equivalent here to iterate over the dynamically enabled/disabled buttons. How best can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

See [`Event.on`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/on/)